# Find the equation for the level surface through the given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Hi I have this equation

$
f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 
$

I would like the find the equation for the level surface that have the point (0,1,1)

Does anyone have tips to find it?

Thank

Comment: Hint: Determine what is $f(0, 1, 1)$.

Comment: Does it is simple as $x^2+y^2=1$ ?

Comment: Indeed the answer is $x^2+y^2=1$.